# Node Express REST hosted in Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am thinking of setting up Google Cloud Run to host Docker container services.  If the existing service is a Node - Express REST service listening on a port, do I need to remove Express, so it isn't constantly running / listening and charged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your existing service is an Express app, you are all set.

You will not be charged when you are not receiving any request.

Just package it in a container using a `Dockerfile` and you can deploy it to Cloud Run. Take a look at [the Node.js sample in the quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy)

Answer (score 2):

No, your container is only scaled up when it is receiving incoming requests. See "Cloud Run container instances" in the [Cloud Run Resource model docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/resource-model).